# Vimscript - split function call to multiple lines

Tags: vim, neovim

I'm trying to write a vimscript that converts a line like this:

```
    myFuncCall(param1, param2, param3="hey", param4)
```

To:

```
    myFuncCall(param1,
        param2,
        param3="hey",
        param4
    )
```

While maintaining and adding indentation. So far I have:

```
function SplitParamLines() abort
    let f_line_num = line(".")
    let indent_length = indent(f_line_num)
    echom indent_length
    echom f_line_num
    .s/\s*,/,\r/g
    nohlsearch
    0t)a<cr>
endfunction
```

How do I indent lines using vimscript?

Why does the last line produces this?:

```
Error detected while processing function SplitParamLines:
line    7:
E14: Invalid address
```

Comment: Will your arguments ever include an argument with a comma in it? As in `func(“lastname, firstname”)`? If so, your regex will break. I guess in that case you could manually do it, but I figured I would point it out.

Comment: @JakeGrossman thanks, but I'm willing to face those edge-cases manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are 2 options which I chose to use both:

1. Using this incredible plugin - [Splitjoin.vim](https://github.com/AndrewRadev/splitjoin.vim)
2. Using this simple function:

```
" Every parameter in its own line
function SplitParamLines() abort
    let f_line_num = line(".")
    let indent_length = indent(f_line_num)
    exe ".s/\s*,/,\r" . repeat(" ", indent_length + &shiftwidth - 1) . "/g"
    nohlsearch
    " execute "normal! 0t)a\<cr>\<esc>"
endfunction
nnoremap <silent> <leader>( :call SplitParamLines()<cr>
```

Although not perfect, it works :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute something that you would have typed, you need `:normal`. If there are special characters, then you'll also need `:exe` and to escape these special characters. IOW

```
:exe "normal! 0t)i\<cr>"
```

Comment: I want to split ANY language's function call, not vimscript. I need to figure out how to write the vimscript function to do that for me.